# Destructuring primitive values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, destructuring

The doc page for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#destructuring_primitive_values) says

> This means if you try to destruct a primitive value, the value will
> get wrapped into the corresponding wrapper object and the property is
> accessed on the wrapper object.

Does this mean the following code?:

```
const { a, toFixed } = 1;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const { a, toFixed } = {1};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means that your 1 is turned into a Number instance, and then the destructuring acts on that.

So it's like

```
const { a, toFixed } = new Number(1);
```

The primitive value types number, string, and boolean all have corresponding wrapper types.

Answer (score 2):

Every primitive type in `javascript` has its corresponding object.

In your example, the primitive type is number, so the corresponding object is [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number)

So, it will be equivalent to

```
const { a, toFixed } = new Number(1);
```

Comment: I think @Pointy is right. `new Number(x)` is different than `Number(x)`.

Comment: `Number(1)` returns the primitive value 1, not a Number instance.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `new`.